# How to find mongo documents containing a value within a list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Is there a mongo find method to find documents containing a value within a list? For instance, I know the following find query `await Devices.find({NotificationId: "1234567890"});` will find all documents with NotificationId being 1234567890, but what if NotificationId was an array? Is there a query to find a mongo document which contains a specific value within an array?

For instance, given that I have a mongo document looking like the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b00635b37285b6cb0625d73"),
    "NotificationId" : [ 
        "98543813", 
        "98543811", 
        null
    ],
    "SerialNumber" : "1234567890"
}
```

Is there a way to find this mongo document given that I only know one of it's NotificationIds? I'm thinking something like `await Devices.find({"98543813" $in NotificationId})`, but that's not it.

Any assistance with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: your first try will work in both string and an array of string. `{NotificationId: "1234567890"}`